# Setting dynamic position of a widget by layout in Kivy

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

The thing I would like to receive seems to be very simple; I would like to change the size and position of my `Label` and `TextInput` widget, being dynamically resizable simultaneously. As these parameters are controlled by layouts, I was playing with linking my `TextInput` to the `FloatLayout` and my `Label` to `AnchorLayout` but it didn't help much. What am I doing wrong ?

**Desirable outcome:**

- text from a `Label` is centralised on the bottom of that layer
- TextInput comprises 20% of the layer it currently fills in terms of height and 80% in terms of width

**What am I getting:**
[TextInput completely disappears after linking FloatLayout to it, text in a label is not changing position at all](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DgApA.png)

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.anchorlayout import AnchorLayout
from kivy.core.window import Window
from kivy.utils import get_color_from_hex


class SearchPerformer(GridLayout):
    pass


class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return SearchPerformer()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    Window.clearcolor = get_color_from_hex('#F9E29C')

MyApp().run()
```

and my KV file where I've defined UI:

```
<SearchPerformer>
GridLayout:
    size: root.size
    cols: 2
    rows: 2

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        rows: 2
        cols: 1
        AnchorLayout:
            Label:
                text: "MAKE"
                font_size: 60
                anchor_x: "center"
                anchor_y: "bottom" # Although specifying bottom, my text label doesn't move to the bottom of the layer

        FloatLayout: # When FloatLayout is added, TextInput automatically disappears
            TextInput:
                border: (50, 50, 50, 50)
                multiline: False
                font_size: 30
                size_hint: .8, .2 # So then 80% width and 50% in height of this layer does not work as well...



    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        rows: 2
        cols: 1
        Label:
            text: "MODEL"
            font_size: 60
        TextInput:
            border: (50, 50, 50, 50)
            multiline: False
            font_size: 30

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        rows: 2
        cols: 1
        Label:
            text: "YEAR"
            font_size: 60
        TextInput:
            border: (50, 50, 50, 50)
            multiline: False
            font_size: 30

    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        rows: 2
        cols: 1
        Label:
            text: "ENGINE"
            font_size: 60
        TextInput:
            border: (50, 50, 50, 50)
            multiline: False
            font_size: 30
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using the `AnchorLayout`, the `anchor_x` and `anchor_y` properties are part of the `AnchorLayout`, not its child. So that part of your `kv` should be:

```
    AnchorLayout:
        anchor_x: "center"
        anchor_y: "bottom"
        Label:
            text: "MAKE"
            font_size: 60
```

And when you use `FloatLayout`, you must position its children either with `pos_hint` or `pos`. But note that `pos_hint` positions children relative to the position of the `FloatLayout`. So using:

```
pos_hint: {'x':0, 'y':0}
```

positions the child in the lower left corner of the `FloatLayout`, but:

```
pos: (0, 0)
```

which is the default, positions the child at the lower left corner of the display (perhaps not even inside the `FloatLayout`). So to get the `TextInput` where you want it, you can use the above `pos_hint`.

Another possibility is to use `RelativeLayout`, where the `pos` coordinates are relative to the position of the `RelativeLayout`. In that case the default `pos` of `(0,0)` will position the child `TextInput` where you want it.

You can adjust the position of the text within a `Label` using `halign` and `valign`, but only if the `text_size` is larger than required for the actual text (the `texture_size`). So, for example, here is a way to adjust the position of the text in one of your `Labels`:

```
    Label:
        text: "ENGINE"
        font_size: 60
        text_size: self.size  # sets text size to allow below alignments to work
        valign: 'bottom'
        halign: 'center'
```

Comment: Thanks @John for the answer! I fixed and figured out the part with `FloatLayout`, but reformating `AnchorLayout` as you said doesn't change the way how the text display. I guess, the whole `Label` tries to be alocated in the x centrer and y bottom, not only the sheer text inside of it, and that's why it doesn't change the apperance on the screen. I've tried to change the size of that `Label` then, but it was not what I supposed to be as well, cause it only changed the division for `Label` and `TextInput` inside of that `BoxLayout`

Comment: What can I do to move the text only from the Label to the boundary with TextInput ?

Comment: I've tried with `halign` and `padding_y` but with no effects